# Can I use an if on foreach in such a case?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a little problem, am trying to read values from mysql table. I have done research and could not find a definite or conclusive answer on this. I will describe the problem:

1. select data from mysql table using a where e.g where gender=female.
2. count the results and return the count - just to help know how many records were found
3. compare a value in table, e.g 'taken' and 'available',
4. `if 'taken' = 'available'` in the first record, go to next record(and compare again), if not perform a specific operation in this case can be update or insert or anything of that sort.

the first three are ok and the only problem is, part 4. Kindly help. This is a php problem. Looking forward for your help.

Comment: Why not just get all the records that fulfil this condition by including it in your SQL statement, instead of wasting time and processing power to compare values using PHP?

Comment: @theommessin I would love to know that. Would you kindly give some more info

Comment: For example: `SELECT * from \`users\` WHERE \`gender\` = 'female' AND \`taken\` = 'available'`

Comment: Are you trying to build an online dating site by any chance? XD

Comment: actually, `taken` is a column with integer values, same case with `available`. Say am checking if a hotel room reserved for ladies. Check if the hall offered is full then check next as you allocate them rooms.

Comment: Well, a table attribute has a set data type in MySQL. If you can have 'available', which is a string (eg. type VARCHAR), then your integers will not actually be represented as integers. In any case, this code should still work.

Comment: not a dating site sir

Comment: What kind of integer values are present in those columns? Are they boolean style `1` or `0` or are they counts? Id's?

Comment: they are like room count in this case. Such that `available` represents total rooms while `taken` represents all rooms which have been occupied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was said, if you're merely going to skip the record then you may as well not retrieve them in the first place (and thus incur the overhead for having to extract them into PHP memory, etc):

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` WHERE `gender` = 'female' AND `taken` = `available`;
```

However, if you have a specific reason to do this, you can merely do the following:

```
foreach ($hotels as $hotel) {
    // skip if the item is not available, logic can be changed if necessary
    if ($hotel->taken >= $hotel->available) continue;

    // do the other work here...
}
```

I interpreted your conditions a little here, assuming you wanted to skip people who aren't 'available'. Though it does look like you wanted the opposite, in which case you can switch the logic in the sql from `!=` to `=` and in php from `!=` to `==`.

**Updated:** To reflect additional comments made.

Comment: Yes! This what I was looking for but with a little modification.

Answer (score 0):

Create connection to your database using mysqli or by using PDO.

```
$db = new PDO($mysqlhost,$username,$password);
$statement = $db->prepare($sqlstatement);
$rows = $statement->execute();
foreach($rows->fetch() as $row)
{
    if($row['column_name']==something)
{
   //do work
}
else
{
  //do work
}
}
```